# Does Rikulo Stream support server-side SSL?

Tags: ssl, rikulo

In my search to find SSL support, I have looked at the Rikulo Security package, which unfortunately does not support SSL.

If it does not support SSL, it would be nice if the url mapping could define this somehow (similar to how security plugin does it in Grails), and with config parameter for the path of the SSL certificate.

An example of the way it could be configured:

```
 var urlMap = {
      "/": home,
      "/login": SECURE_CHANNEL(login),  // I made this part up
       .....
  };

 new StreamServer(uriMapping: urlMap)
  ..start(port: 8080);
```

Has anyone got SSL working with Rikulo Stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shall use `startSecure()`:

```
new StreamServer()
  ..start(port: 80)
  ..startSecure(address: "11.22.33.44", port: 443);
```

Second, the routing map shall be the same, i.e., no special handling.

If you'd like to have different routing map for HTTP and HTTPS, you can start two servers:

```
new StreamServer(mapping1).start(port: 80);
new StreamServer(mapping2).startSecure(address: "11.22.33.44", port: 443);
```

Comment: Tom, Thanks for the quick response. I will set this up.